# How to run jupyter notebook in airflow

Tags: jupyter, airflow

My code is written in jupyter and saved as **.ipynb** format.

We want to use airflow to schedule the execution and define the dependencies.

How can the notebooks be executed in airflow?

I know I can convert them to python files first but the graphs generated on the fly will be difficult to handle.

Is there are any easier solution? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also use combination of [airflow + papermill](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.10/howto/operator/papermill.html).

#### Papermill

Papermill is a tool for running jupyter notebooks with parameters: https://github.com/nteract/papermill
Running a jupyter notebook is very easy, you can do it from python script:

```py
import papermill as pm

pm.execute_notebook(
   'path/to/input.ipynb',
   'path/to/output.ipynb',
   parameters = dict(alpha=0.6, ratio=0.1)
)
```

or from CLI:

```sh
$ papermill local/input.ipynb s3://bkt/output.ipynb -p alpha 0.6 -p l1_ratio 0.1
```

and it will run a notebook from the input path, create a copy in the output path and update this copy after each cell run.

#### Airflow Integration

To integrate it with Airflow, there is a dedicated papermill operator for running parametrized notebooks: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/operator/papermill.html
You can setup the same input/output/paramters arguments directly in the DAG definition and use the templating for the aifrlow variables:

```py
run_this = PapermillOperator(
    task_id="run_example_notebook",
    dag=dag,
    input_nb="/tmp/hello_world.ipynb",
    output_nb="/tmp/out-{{ execution_date }}.ipynb",
    parameters={"msgs": "Ran from Airflow at {{ execution_date }}!"}
)
```

Answer (score 6):

We encountered this problem before and spent quite a couple of days to solve it.
We packaged it as a docker file and published on github https://github.com/michaelchanwahyan/datalab.

It is done by modifing an open source package ***nbparameterize*** and integrating the passing arguments such as **execution_date**. Graph generated on the fly can also be updated and saved within inside the notebook.

When it is executed

1. the notebook will be read and inject the parameters
2. the notebook is executed and the output will overwrite the original path

Besides, it also installed and configured common tools such as spark, keras, tensorflow, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use Ploomner (disclaimer: I'm the author). It uses papermill under the hood to build multi-stage pipelines. Tasks can be notebooks, scripts, functions, or any combination of them. You can run locally, Airflow, or Kubernetes (using Argo workflows).

This is how a pipeline declaration looks like:

```yaml
tasks:
  - source: notebook.ipynb
    product:
      nb: output.html
      data: output.csv

  - source: another.ipynb
    product:
      nb: another.html
      data: another.csv
```

- [Repository](https://github.com/ploomber/ploomber)
- [Exporting to Airflow](https://soopervisor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/airflow.html)
- [Exporting to Kubernetes](https://soopervisor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kubernetes.html)
- [Sample pipelines](https://github.com/ploomber/projects)